# Is it possible to record external HDMI device in Android TV app?

Tags: android-tv

For example, if there is a gaming console (i.e PlayStation) connected to HDMI input in a TV with Android TV. Then, is it possible to record the video going through this HDMI input with a 3rd party app?

In my question I'm referring to Android's [TV input framework](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/)

Thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 0):

The TV Input Framework docs mentions that [it supports TV recording APIs](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/#viewing).

[DVR](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/#support_for_third-party_tv_inputs)

> For devices on Android 7.0 and above, the TV App must support the
>   Android framework [TV recording
>   APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvRecordingClient.html),
>   to support, list, and play recorded programs.
>
> This allows device manufacturers to plug their DVR subsystems into TIF
>   and dramatically reduce the integration effort it takes to enable or
>   integrate DVR functionality on a TV device. It also enables third
>   parties to provide aftermarket DVR systems that can be plugged into an
>   Android TV device.
>
> In addition to recording live content, the TV App also handles
>   resource conflict. For example, if the device has two tuners, it can
>   record two programs at the same time. If the user asks to record
>   three, the TV App must handle the conflict and should either surface a
>   notification or request that the user schedules a priority for these
>   requests.

However I don't have code samples for you as I haven't experimented with this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the [MediaProjection API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) and record this with a [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html). Jake Wharton's app Telecine follows this approach and you can find the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine).

The benefit is that these APIs were introduced with Lollipop, so you can use them on all Android TV devices. However I just started experimenting with Android TV, so I can not tell from personal experiences.

Comment: Thank you! Seems useful. Please let us know how is it working with Android TV